# cant import pyautogui, no module named 'Xlib'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I want to import pyautogui using PyCharm but it keeps showing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled2/ghea.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Xlib.display import Display
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Xlib'
```

There were some similar questions and I tried answers but none of them did work.

i tried:

sudo apt-get install  python-xlib

pip install python3_xlib

sudo apt-get install python3-xlib

Comment: It looks like you're using a virtual environment inside of PyCharm, so installing into the system python with `sudo apt install python3-xlib` won't work unless you have **Inherit global site-packages** checked as mentioned [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html). But there should also be some way to have PyCharm install it into the virtual environment (using requirements.txt for example)

Comment: so what should i do now? If i change to windows (i have dualboot) will the same problem occur? I am beginner and dont really understand what do you mean there...

Comment: A quick solution is to just go to the link and follow the instructions to set the **Inherit global site-packages** option. Switching to Windows would also solve the problem since it looks like `pyautogui` has no dependencies when running on Windows. But that seems excessive.